# Pandas Series And Read CSV

Tags: csv, pandas

I'm using a regular dictionary to store matrices and then converting that dict to a Pandas Series and write it out to a CSV. I then use pd.read_csv() on the csv file but the returned items are all strings, literally a string of the entire matrix of values. Anyway I can make it floats?

Comment: post raw input data to show your problem

Answer (score 0):

The datatypes to read in are an argument to `read_csv`. From the function help:

```
dtype : Type name or dict of column -> type
    Data type for data or columns. E.g. {'a': np.float64, 'b': np.int32}
```

so you'd make a read call like:

```
mypd=pd.read_csv('my.csv', dtype={'a': np.float64, 'b': np.int32})
```

where a, b, etc match your input file.

You can also cast the type of a column after it's been read into a DataFrame.